# Black and White Magento Visual Swatches displaying Hex instead of color swatch

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, swatches, color-swatches

We have swatches configured for our configurable products for users to select the color of the shirt from, everything seems to work fine except for the two black and white swatches, instead of displaying the color swatch like the rest of the colors do, they simply display the corresponding hex value (FFFFFF, 000000). Screenshot is below.
[image]

Has anybody else ran into this issue or know a fix for it?